# How can I add text to a specific 'Edit Page'?

Tags: templates, hooks, page-template

I have a specific Page, that I do not wish to be edited.  As such, I would like to place a 'Do Not Edit This Page' message within a specific 'Edit Page' file as follows:

[image]

Any ideas on how this can be achieved or what I could search for within the WordPress Codex/Developer Resource?  Ideally, I would like to be able to create some sort of Template File but if not, I guess the solution would involve the use of Hooks within the `functions.php` file?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you would indeed have to include some code in the `functions.php` of your theme. You can use [`admin_notices`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) to add a note to this specific page like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse332074_donotedit' );
function wpse332074_donotedit () {
 $screen = get_current_screen();
 if ($screen->post_type == 'page') {
   $variable = $_GET['post'];
   if ($variable == id_of_page_as_integer) { 
     $class = 'notice notice-error';
     $message = __( 'Do not edit this page!', 'your-text-domain' );
     echo '<div class="' . $class . '"><p>' . $message . '</p></div>';
     }
   }
 }
```

However, this would allow people to ignore the message and still edit the page. If you really don't want the page to be edited, you can remove the edit, quick edit and trash links in the all pages screen by using the [`page_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_row_actions/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'wpse332074_disable_edit', 10, 2 );
function wpse332074_disable_edit ($actions, $post) {
  if ( $post->ID == id_of_page_as_integer ) {
    unset( $actions['edit'] );
    unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
    unset( $actions['trash'] );
    }
  return $actions;
  }
```

Beware that any changes to `functions.php` will be lost when the theme is updated. The proper way to do this is to build a child theme.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have entered your suggestion, within the `functions.php`, assigning the relevant Page ID, but it results in the website producing an Error Page.

Comment: Which snippet did you try? What does the error say?

Comment: I tried both snippets, which generated a 'HTTP ERROR 500' page.  Tried to identify the issue, through a method of elimination but to no success.

Comment: I noticed there were missing parentheses, after the `wpse332074_donotedit` function.  Once I inserted these, the `HTTP ERROR 500` stopped displaying.  That being said, the relevant text does not show at all with the WP Dashboard.  I have yet to figure out what is causing the `HTTP ERROR 500` for your second snippet; however.

Comment: Sorry for trying to answer this from the top of my head. I've corrected the code and tested it in my development area.

Comment: Excellent.  Both snippets work; thank you.  I have noticed that `id_of_page_as_integer` works with and without commas.  Does it matter whether the integer is placed within commas or not?

Comment: No it doesn't. PHP will convert the string to an integer if you place the ID between commas.